# How can I start angular server (ng serve) on raspberry pi while it boots up?

Tags: angular, raspberry-pi, boot

I have an angular project running on raspberry pi. It starts the server when I run ng serve manually but I need it getting started automatically when the Raspberry pi boots up.

Comment: Which distro are you running on it?

Comment: desktop based on Debian Buster

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should build your application (with `ng build`) and serve the static files generated using Apache/Nginx/whatever you like.

Way easier than creating a service for `ng serve`.

Or just follow the guidelines over at [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)